# Convert unicode to datetime proper strptime format

Tags: python, django, datetime, unicode, strptime

I am trying to convert a unicode object to a datetime object.

I read through the documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime

and tried

```
datetime.strptime(date_posted, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

but I get the error message `ValueError: time data '2014-01-15T01:35:30.314Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'`

Any feedback on what is the proper format?

I appreciate the time and expertise.

Comment: You're reading the wrong documentation. While `time.strptime` and `datetime.datetime.strptime` are obviously _similar_ functions, they're (as on 2.6+) implemented entirely separately, and have different lists of why they can handle. (`time` just calls your platform's C library; `datetime` manually handles additional format directives are even if your platform doesn't.)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can parse the microseconds:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_posted = '2014-01-15T01:35:30.314Z'
datetime.strptime(date_posted, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

Comment: I thought making `datetime` handle `%f` manually if the platform doesn't was only added in 3.1+, but it looks like it was backported to 2.6 as well. Nice.

Answer (score 12):

One option is to let [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) do the job:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse('2014-01-15T01:35:30.314Z')
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 15, 1, 35, 30, 314000, tzinfo=tzutc())
```