# How to transfer unicode to datetime in python?

Tags: python, json, datetime, rfc3339

I dumps a `datetime` object into to json object and I get:

```
a = u'2015-02-17T15:06:23.869000'
```

How to transfer it back to a datetime object?

Comment: Checkout datetime.strftime in the standard library datetime module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(u"2015-02-17T15:06:23.869000", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 17, 15, 6, 23, 869000)
```

to parse it back to a `datetime` object. JSON has no special representation for a datetime object, so your program encodes it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to let [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) do the job:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> a = u'2015-02-17T15:06:23.869000' 
>>> parser.parse(a)
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 17, 15, 6, 23, 869000)
```

you could also look for some reference here [Convert unicode to datetime proper strptime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151664/convert-unicode-to-datetime-proper-strptime-format)